# ListPicker FullMode Selected Item Color

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to change color of selected ListPicker Item in Full Mode?

What style need to be edited?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do that you will have to create a copy of the [ListPickerPage.xaml](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74775#1510235) file from the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit in your application, change it to meet your requirements, and then on your ListPicker control set the PickerPageUri proprety to the new ListPickerPage.xaml

Comment: Another question: can I set one style of item for standart mode and full mode? At this moment ListPicker items added dynamically and I check, if count of items to add is more than value of ItemCountThreshold property, then I set custom style for every item and add it to ListPicker.Items, else I fill List<string> and assign it List to ListPicker.ItemsSource property. Is more rational way to add items with custom styles into ListPicker? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question: you want to use the same style for standard and FullMode?

Comment: Yes, You a right. I don't know beforehand how many items I need to add to ListPicker, but I want all items in both modes were similar. For example I want to set the Foreground property of selected item to red in both modes independently of current phone theme. Sorry for my English, I'm from Russia...

Comment: Why not just use ListPickerMode = Full and that way it always display in FullMode page? But regarding the question, I think you'll have to set the two styles separatly, one directly in the ListPicker and the other in the picker page...

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-customize-the-listpicker-selected-item

Comment: I downloaded sample from this Q&A, but it is not work in full mode. You can see it after adding some items more in ListPicker. For example, I copied existing three items and added them below. After launching application an exception has occured when I tried to click ListPicker and open it in FullMode.

Comment: Also I tried to fill ListPicker ItemsSource property by List<string> for example, but my first question is still actual.

Comment: This works only when the ListPicker is not in FullMode, but this is not the case this user requested.