# How to customize the full page of a listpicker?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListPicker FullMode Selected Item Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738204/listpicker-fullmode-selected-item-color)

I've a long list of things loading from a listpicker, mostly "useless".

Is there the possibility to add a button on top of the full page opened when I click the listpicker (so when I click on it I only show the most useful things?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you will have to create a copy of the [ListPickerPage.xaml](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74775#1510235) file from the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit in your application, change it to meet your requirements, and then on your ListPicker control set the PickerPageUri proprety to the new ListPickerPage.xaml

Comment: After seeing your solution I have tried it. The background and everything changes BUT the items of the list picker are not shown !! Do you have a workaround?